# how to create recursive merge of 2 sorted lists resulting in sorted merged list

Tags: java, recursion, merge

I am learning about recursion I am trying to return a sorted list by merging 2 sorted lists and am getting lost. I know this is incorrect already but any guidance will help.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> mergeMyList(ArrayList<Integer> list1, 
          ArrayList<Integer> list2)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> tempList = null;  
    int n = list1.size() +list2.size();
    int l = list2.size();

    if ( n == 0  && l == 0)
    {                        
        tempList = list1;
        return tempList;
    }
    if ( n == 0 )
    {                        
        tempList = list2;
        return tempList;
    }
    if ( l == 0)
    {                        
        tempList = list1;   
        return tempList;
    }

    else
    {   
        int x = list1.get(0); 
        int y = list2.get(0);

        if (x < y )
        {
            //  list1.add(x);
            //  list1.add(y); 
            tempList=list1;
            //  list1.remove(0);
            //  list2.remove(0);    

        }
        else
        {
            list1.add(y);                     
            tempList = list1;
            list1.remove(0);
            list2.remove(0);
            tempList = mergeMyList(list1,list2);
        }                   
    }
    tempList = mergeMyList(list1,list2);
    return tempList;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion if you already have the two sorted lists? Just iterate over them and append the greatest value in a new list.

Comment: Its just what I was asked - I am trying to help someone but its a bit beyond my scope

Comment: Thanks Enrique for your comment

Answer (score 0):

It could be done shorted or better, but I think it can be understood.

```
ArrayList<Integer> mergeList(ArrayList<Integer> list1, 
                             ArrayList<Integer> list2)
{
  ArrayList result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  while (list1.size() > 0 && list2.size() > 0)
  {
    if (list1.get(0) < list2.get(0))   
       result.add(list1.remove(0));
    else
       result.add(list2.remove(0));
  }

  while (list1.size() > 0) result.add(list1.remove(0));
  while (list2.size() > 0) result.add(list2.remove(0));

  return result;
}

ArrayList<Integer> QuickSort(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
  if (list.size() < 2)
    return list;

  ArrayList<Integer> left = list.subList(0, list.szie() / 2);
  ArrayList<Integer> right = list.subList(list.szie() / 2, 8);

  return mergeList(QuickSort(left), QuickSort(right));
}
```

It is a full example of quicksort which is recursive. It is fast (kind of), but requires a lot of space, and can overflow the stack if the list is too big.

Recursive merge:

```
ArrayList<Integer> mergeList(ArrayList<Integer> list1, 
                             ArrayList<Integer> list2)
{
  if (list1.size() == 0) return list2;
  if (list2.size() == 0) return list1;

  ArrayList result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  if (list1.get(0) < list2.get(0))   
    result.add(list1.remove(0));
  else
    result.add(list2.remove(0));

  result.addAll(mergeList(list1, list2));

  return result;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matzi I already have a method like this I'm looking for a recursive one - Thank you very much I appreciate your reply.

Comment: I modified it to a full quicksort, which is recursive. Also added the recursive merge which is kinda pointless.

Comment: Thank you Brilliant! so much better than my effort :-)